# Convert comma separated values to key value pair Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array of states in the format

```
('AL','Alabama','AK','Alaska','AR','Arkansas'...)
```

which I want formatted like:

```
[{'AL' => 'Alabama'},...]
```

This is primarily so that I can more easily loop through using the HTML::Template module (https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Template#TMPL_LOOP)

I'm fairly new to perl, so unsure about how to do this sort of action and can't find something similar enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't the following make more sense for HTML::Template?

```
states => [ { id => 'AL', name => 'Alabama' }, ... ]
```

This would allow you to use the following template:

```
<TMPL_LOOP NAME=states>
   <TMPL_VAR NAME=name> (<TMPL_VAR NAME=id>)
</TMPL_LOOP>
```

To achieve that, you can use the following:

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairmap );

states => [ pairmap { +{ id => $a, name => $b } } @states ]
```

That said, you're probably generating HTML.

```
<select name="state">
   <TMPL_LOOP NAME=states>
      <option value="<TMPL_VAR NAME=id_html>"><TMPL_VAR NAME=name_html></option>
   </TMPL_LOOP>
</select>
```

To achieve that, you can use the following:

```
use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairmap );

{
   my %escapes = (
      '&' => '&amp;',
      '<' => '&lt;',
      '>' => '&gt;',
      '"' => '&quot;',
      "'" => '&#39;',
   );

   sub text_to_html(_) { $_[0] =~ s/([&<>"'])/$escapes{$1}/rg }
}

states => [ pairmap { +{ id_html => $a, name_html => $b } } map text_to_html, @states ]
```

Comment: Why do you use version in `use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairmap );`? Without version `use List::Util qw( pairmap );` on List::Util before 1.29 the code with fail `"pairmap" is not exported by the List::Util module`.

Comment: 1) The error message is better because it says how to fix the problem. 2) I don't actually put the version in the `use` statement; I place it in Makefile.PL/Build.PL. This communicates to the reader what version to place in Makefile.PL/Build.PL.

Answer (score 2):

```
use List::Util 1.29;
@state_hashes = List::Util::pairmap { +{ $a => $b } } @states;
```

Comment: Or `use List::Util 1.29 qw( pairmap ); @state_hashes = pairmap { +{ $a => $b } } @states;`. You can still import when specifying a version.

Comment: @ikegami I'm not a big fan of importing

Comment: Fair enough, but others are. (I like to import, but I like to list exactly what I import rather than importing the defaults like you did)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to keep this hash around for later use I think that simply looping through the elements two at a time would be simpler. You can accomplish this type of looping easily with [`splice`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
my @states = ('AL','Alabama','AK','Alaska','AR','Arkansas'...);
while (my ($code, $name) = splice(@states, 0, 2)) {
   # operations here
}
```

Alternatively, you can use this same approach to create the data structure you want:

```
my @states = ('AL','Alabama','AK','Alaska','AR','Arkansas'...);
my @state_hashes = ();
while (my ($code, $name) = splice(@states, 0, 2)) {
   push @state_hashes, { $code => $name };
}
# do w/e you want with @state_hashes
```

Note: splice will remove elements from `@states`

Answer (score 1):

[bundle_by from List::UtilsBy](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::UtilsBy#bundle_by) can easily create this format:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::UtilsBy 'bundle_by';
my @states = ('AL', 'Alabama', 'AK', 'Alaska', 'AR', 'Arkansas', ... );
my @hashes = bundle_by { +{@_} } 2, @states;
```

Answer (score 0):

`map` solution with a few perlish things

```
my @states = ('AL','Alabama','AK','Alaska','AR','Arkansas','VT','Vermont');

my %states;
map { $states{$states[$_]} = $states[$_+1] unless $_%2 } 0..$#states;
```